# Negate comparison chain

Tags: java, comparison, guava

I wrote something like

```
@Override public int compareTo(Cuboid that) {
    return -ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(this.d0, that.d0)
            .compare(this.d1, that.d1)
            .compare(this.d2, that.d2)
            .result();
}
```

To reverse the order, I simply negated the result, but now I see it was wrong as the docs says

> Ends this comparison chain and returns its result: a value having the
>   same sign as the first nonzero comparison result in the chain, or zero if
>   every result was zero.

So `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is an allowed return value and then the negation fails. In the source code, I can see that nothing but -1, 0, and +1 gets ever returned, but this isn't something I'd like to depend on.

Instead of the negation I could swap all the operands. Simple and ugly, but I'm curious if there's a better solution.

Comment: In their `ReverseOrdering` class, the Guava team just swaps the arguments.

Comment: Comparator.reverse() delegates to Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator), which returns a comparator that just swaps the arguments.  So swapping the arguments looks like the way to go, provided you can't replace ComparisonChain with Comparator.comparingInt(c -> c.c0).thenComparingInt(c -> c.c1) ... .reversed() and let the JDK devs worry about the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a signum function using no floating point, namely `Integer#signum(int)` and it's about 3.5 times faster then `Math.signum` with the cast to `double`.

---

Out of curiosity, the fastest solution is

```
return -((x&1) | (x>>1));
```

but only by about 10%.

Answer (score 3):

One option that may be more clear than reversing the `compare` arguments would be to compare each pair of arguments with the reverse of their natural ordering:

```
.compare(this.d0, that.d0, Ordering.natural().reverse())
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's better (personally I don't like to involve floating point operations), but you could send it through [Math#signum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28float%29):

```
return -Math.signum( .... );
```

I'd probably just swap the operands.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
int temp = ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(this.d0, that.d0)
            .compare(this.d1, that.d1)
            .compare(this.d2, that.d2)
            .result();

return temp == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : -temp;
```